# Java change text between two substrings

Tags: java, string

Assume I have this string:

```
String s = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..";
```

And I want to change the values between the `<change>` and `</change>` elements (I want to encode them, or decode them, it's just an example in this case, note that to encode these values, I need the value between the tags (before the changement) itself too).

What's the best way to do this?
I was thinking about using the s.replaceAll() function but I'm not sure how I can use it for this example.

I can't just use an XML parser because the text between the tags might contain some special characters like < and >, that will cause errors when using an XML parser.

I'm using Java.

Comment: It looks like job for XML parser rather then regex.

Comment: Yea something I forgot to say in the post is that between the tags there might be some < and > characters that will cause some errors when using an XML parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since as you claim this is not valid XML document you can try with regex. To replace founded value with its new version you can use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` from `Matcher` class.

- `appendReplacement` replace founded value with its new version. You decide how you want to replace it.
- `appendTail` adds part after last match to buffer.

To find match between `<change>` and `</change>` you can use `<change>(.*?)</change>` regex - if you want dot to represent all characters (including line separators like `\n`) you should use `DOTALL` flag from `Pattern`.

Demo:

```
String input = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<change>(.*?)</change>",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while(m.find()){
    String valueFromTags = m.group(1);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, valueFromTags.toUpperCase());
    //                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // you decide what to put as replacement of original value
    // toUpperCase is just example
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
random text blah blah HELLO more random text HEY ..
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex, but it's a bit slow.

```
String newString = s.replaceAll("(?<=<change>).+?(?=<\\/change>)", "Your new string");
```

This means that you can have extra < or > characters within the change bit, and it will still work perfectly.

**EDIT :** if you wish to use the original word as well you can use this:

```
    String regexPattern = "(?<=<change>).+?(?=<\\/change>)";
    String originalString = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    Matcher matches = pattern.matcher(originalString);

    if (matches.find()){
        String originalText = matches.group(0);
        String t = originalString.replaceAll(regexPattern, originalText + " whatever you want to add");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No matches found");
    }
```

Comment: Problem is that I need the substring between the <change> and </change> tags to generate the string to replace it with

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use XML notation?

You can use `@change` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
    String s = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> .."
    String formatted = s.replaceAll("hello", "YOUR CHANGE HERE");
    formatted = s.replaceAll("hey", "YOUR CHANGE HERE");
```

Or you could take advantage of the regex in replace all:

**EDIT:**

```
    String s = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..";
    String formatted = s.replaceAll("<change>(\\w)+</change>", "YOUR CHANGE HERE");
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: The problem about this is that the text between the tags can be different everytime

Comment: But in order to replace the text between the tags with the encoded text of the text itself, I need to have the value between the two tags too

Comment: Pattern and matcher class is the way to go in this case if you want to evaluate the content within tag. If you use the regex I gave, you would ask the matcher for group(1) for the content and then you would replace string accordingly.

Comment: `(\\w)+` will place last letter from match in group 1. You probably wanted `(\\w+)`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting puzzle.

Assuming you WANT to change the tags:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..";
        System.out.println("BEFORE:"+s);
        System.out.println("AFTER :"+replace(s, "HI", "HELLO"));
    }

    private static String replace(String source, String ...replace)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return null;
        // ... more checks here
        int index=0, next, m=0;
        do
        {
            index = source.indexOf("<change>", index);
            next = source.indexOf("</change>", index)+"</change>".length();
            if (index>0)
            {
                source = source.substring(0, index) + replace[m] + source.substring(next);
                m++;
            }
        }
        while (index>0);
        return source;
    }

}
```

The output would be

```
BEFORE:random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> ..
AFTER :random text blah blah HI more random text HELLO ..
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good Idea

Looking for occurrence **<** and **>** and replacing those. Assuming there will be no generalized  "<>" in the String

```
String s = "random text blah blah <change>hello</change> more random text <change>hey</change> .."
 String formatted = s.replaceAll("\\>", "><").replaceAll("\\<","/><");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution taht works with regular expression:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String SIMPLE_TAG_REGEX = "<(.+?)>(.+?)</(.+?)>";
        final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(SIMPLE_TAG_REGEX);

        final String s = "hello <foo>bar</foo> world, <lorem>ipsum</lorem>";
        final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String startTag = matcher.group(1);
            final String content = matcher.group(2);
            final String endTag = matcher.group(3);
            System.out.println(startTag + ", " + endTag + ": " + content);
        }
    }
```

Prints out:

```
    foo, foo: bar
    lorem, lorem: ipsum
```

Please check if `startTag.equals(endTag)`. A regex can't do that in theorie (and praxis :) )!