# Replace multiple substrings within a string

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace certain substrings with a replacement, both defined within a Hashmap. An example is the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    private static HashMap<String, String> conversionTable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initConversionTable();
        System.out.println(convertNumbers("la1"));
        System.out.println(convertNumbers("la1, lb3"));
    }

    private static String convertNumbers(String text) {
        String regex = "([aub][1-3])";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
            text  = m.replaceAll(conversionTable.get(m.group()));
        }

        return text;
    }

    private static void initConversionTable() {
        conversionTable = new HashMap<>();
        conversionTable.put("a1", "A1");
        conversionTable.put("a2", "A2");
        conversionTable.put("a3", "A3");
        conversionTable.put("u1", "U1");
        conversionTable.put("u2", "U2");
        conversionTable.put("u3", "U3");
        conversionTable.put("b1", "B1");
        conversionTable.put("b2", "B2");
        conversionTable.put("b3", "B3");
    }
}
```

For input data

```
la1
la1, lb3
```

The expected result should be

```
lA1
lA1, lB3
```

but is

```
lA1
lA1, lA1
```

Until now I have not succeeded finding a solution with a Matcher. Is there such a solution? Of course I could go through each Entry of the HashMap and do the replacement, but I would like to solve it with a Matcher, because I fear that for a very long Hashmap and many strings this could influence the performance.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As explained in accepted answer problem is that `replaceAll` replaces all occurrences of regex match first time it will `find()` which will prevent other matches and proper replacements. But to solve this problem don't use `replaceFirst`. Instead use proper tool to handle precisely this kind of scenarios when we want to one match with another dynamically determined replacement (like value based on key in map). So use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` from Matcher class.

Comment: I closed your question as duplicate of question where you can see one of solutions where these methods are used. You can also take a look at other examples like http://stackoverflow.com/a/25081783/1393766, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689796/1393766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use replaceAll method so this will happen.

Step 1:

```
la1
la1, lb3
```

will go into loop because m.Find() returns true. It will find the first pattern "la1". Now you will get the conversion from table which is "lA1" and replace ALL occurences of the pattern, which is both "la1" and "lb3".
Then the loop will not iterate again because the output is already

```
lA1
lA1, lA1
```

To fix the problem you need to replace just one occurence with the coresponding value, otherwise you will replace all of them with the first one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the problem is now clear to me. I have replaced the line, in which the replacement takes places, with `text  = text.replace(m.group(), conversionTable.get(m.group()));`. But why does `text  = m.replaceFirst(conversionTable.get(m.group()));` not work, i.e. empty result?

Comment: Maybe you need to reset the matcher for the loop to properly evaluate again: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-

Comment: I just saw it too and tried, but it did not work. Further reading should solve the problem, but I will stick now to my first solution, otherwise it will get to complicated. Thank you again :)